# Titanium Mobile - Parsing xml response from a soap webservice with suds.js

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, titanium-mobile, suds

I'm trying to receive informations from a soap webservice but i really don't know how to display the results i get.

I can only show the first global tag named :

This gives me a long xml result : **response**.

When i try with another tagname, it doesn't gives my any result.

Here is my code:

```
Ti.include('suds.js');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#ffffff'

});

var view = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    layout: 'Vertical',
    contentHeight:'auto'
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    color : '#000000'
});

var url = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx";

var callParams = {
    CountryName : 'belgium'
};

var suds = new SudsClient({
    endpoint : url,
    targetNamespace : 'http://www.webserviceX.NET'
});

suds.invoke('GetCitiesByCountry', callParams, function(xmlDoc) {

    var response = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('GetCitiesByCountryResult');

    if (response && response.length > 0) {

        label.text = response.item(0).text;
    } else {
        label.text = 'NOT OK';
    }

});

view.add(label);
win.add(view);
win.open();
```

The response is something like:

```
<NewDataSet>
 <Table>
  <Country>Belgium</Country>
  <City>Antwerpen</City>
 </Table>
 <Table>
  <Country>Belgium</Country>
  <City>Beauvechain</city>
 </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

The response.length = 1

Could only display reponse.item(0).text i don't want all the stuff but only for exemple a loop that gives me only the Cities.

When i try to change the getElementsByTagName('GetCitiesByCountryResult') with getElementsByTagName('Table') the message "not ok" appears.

Please help, what can i do to parse all the informations i need ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this function its working...
If you want to display the first tag then use only getFirstChild(),
if you want to display the other tags then use this getFirstChild().getNextSibling()

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As is your answer is kind of hard to understand. Posting an example in code form would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should try storing the response in array first and then you can easily extract the information you want.
for ex:
        var show=[];
        for(var i=0;i